# Why do I get rasters with different resolution from the same dataframe in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm working with a dataframe in R that has this structure:

```
summary(data)
       X                Y               Z             type          
 Min.   :  2.94   Min.   :22.48   Min.   :1.000   Length:225176     
 1st Qu.: 22.39   1st Qu.:48.17   1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character  
 Median : 29.64   Median :52.19   Median :1.000   Mode  :character  
 Mean   : 29.68   Mean   :51.79   Mean   :1.007                     
 3rd Qu.: 39.30   3rd Qu.:56.01   3rd Qu.:1.000                     
 Max.   :150.47   Max.   :69.26   Max.   :2.000                     

str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  225176 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X   : num  38.3 38.4 38.4 38.5 38.5 ...
 $ Y   : num  63.4 63.4 63.4 63.4 63.4 ...
 $ Z   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ type: chr  "buffer" "buffer" "buffer" "buffer" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

table(data$type)
type
    buffer   presence pseudo.abs 
    222436       1646       1094
```

it is a raster in lat/lon projection representing the data I extracted for a species. All the points were extracted in a gis environment (GRASS GIS) from the same raster map, so we can say that this dataframe is a subsample of this raster map.

My goal is to make a raster using the presence and buffer rows of this dataframe, but I got this error:

```
library(raster)
raster <- rasterFromXYZ(filter(data, type!="pseudo.abs")[,1:3]) # filtering out unnecessary rows

Error in rasterFromXYZ(filter(data, type!="pseudo.abs")[,1:3]) : 
  x cell sizes are not regular
```

then I checked the buffer and the presence data separately and came out that they have different resolution:

```
data.presence <- rasterFromXYZ(filter(data, type=="presence")[,1:3])

data.presence
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 413, 807, 333291  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04489828, 0.04489264  (x, y)
extent     : 8.258507, 44.49142, 41.49054, 60.0312  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : presence 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)

data.buffer <- rasterFromXYZ(filter(data, type=="buffer")[,1:3])

data.buffer
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 515, 934, 481010  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04899959, 0.04900172  (x, y)
extent     : 2.915476, 48.68109, 38.14953, 63.38541  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : presence 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

How it can be possible that they have different resolution even though they were extracted using the same raster as input?

Is there any solution to convert thi dataframe in a single raster or to merge the presence and buffer rows in a single raster?

Answer (score 0):

> How it can be possible that they have different resolution even though they were extracted using the same raster as input?

That not unexpected. The resolution is not known to `rasterFromXYZ` (as you do not set the `res` argument). It tries to find the lowest resolution supported by the points. If no two neighboring cells were sampled, the resulting resolution would be lower. What *is* the original resolution?

> All the points were extracted in a gis environment (GRASS GIS) from the same raster map, so we can say that this dataframe is a subsample of this raster map.

The coordinates are probably for the points you used to extract data, not for the centers of the grid cells that they fall in.

Either way, you are going about this in a good way. If you start out with raster data, you should not use `rasterFromXYZ`. You can find the cell that a point belongs to with `cellFromXY` and use these to set the values you want to set. You can also get the cell number when you extract raster values in R. Perhaps you can edit your question, or ask a new one, by creating a small example in R. Right now your data come from nowhere, your approach is suboptimal, and your assumptions seem to be wrong; that makes it difficult to help.